# Laravel login page not found

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I've made some changes in `web.php`

I changed the route from this

```
Route::get('/location/{location}', 'LocationController@show')
    ->name('location.details');
```

to this

```
Route::get('/{location?}', 'LocationController@show')
    ->name('location.details');
```

Now when visiting `/admin` or `/login`, this 404 error is thrown:

> 404 Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

before I made the change everything worked.

What is wrong with my routing?

**Route:** web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'StartpageController@index')->name('startpage');

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function ()
{
    Route::name('admin.')->group(function ()
    {
        Route::middleware('auth')->group(function ()
        {
            Route::get('/', function ()
            {
                return view('admin');
            });

            Route::resource('location','AdminLocationController');

        });
    });
});

Route::get('/{location?}', 'LocationController@show')->name('location.details');


Auth::routes();
```

**Controller:** LocationController.php

```
class LocationController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Locations $location)
    {
        return view('location.show', compact('location'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route `Route::get('/{location?}'` is catching all the requests. /login and /admin both satisfy that route.

Either redefine it (rollback the change) or put that route last in your `web.php` or add a constraint on [the route variable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

```
Route::get('/{location?}', 'LocationController@show')->whereNumber('location')->name('location.details');
```

Comment: To put that route last has worket. Thanks. There are any disadvantage?

Comment: @lyze no not really, just consider that it will try to catch any call that satisfies it.